# Let $U, V$ be vector spaces and $X, Y$ their respective subspaces. Show $(U \times V)/(X \times Y) \cong (U/X) \times (V/Y)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to apply the third and potentially second isomorphism theorems, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

Comment: This is also true for arbitrary $R$-modules and groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having trouble wth the second and third isomorphism theorems here is because they are irrelevant.

Try finding an obvious map from $U\times V\to U/X\times V/Y$ and applying the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it directly.

$(u_1,v_1) \sim (u_2,v_2) $ **iff** 
there exists $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ such that $u_1-u_2 = x, v_1-v_2 = y$
**iff**
there exists $x \in X$ such that $u_1-u_2 = x$ and there exists $y \in Y$ such that $v_1-v_2 = y$ **iff**
$u_1 \sim u_2$ and $v_1 \sim v_2$.

This suggests the map $[(u,v)] \mapsto ([u], [v])$.